# Parenting of Movie Clips ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip

I have some mc'S stored in an array. I put the mc on the stage and  I want that when I click on one of them this one should be in foreground and the others in the background.
How can I do the parentig?

Thank you for your time

Comment: looking over your last 7 questions, I feel like I enough information to just build the application you are trying to make and give it to you... What code have you tried so far yourself to accomplish this?

Comment: :)) i want to create a puzzle game only to improve my knowledge in AS3 because I started to learn AS3 4 weeks ago.
I have to make the parenting and the game solution like when all the puzzle pieces are in the right order than the hole image should by displayed.
can you help me?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your MCs are in the same container, i.e., another MovieClip/Sprite, you can either update the child index of the "clicked mc" or just add it to the container again.

This would be your click handler:

```
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //addChild puts the target clip on the top of the display list
    e.target.parent.addChild(e.target); 
}
```

It would be cleaner to reference the container by its' instance name (like container.addChild()) rather than using e.target.parent. If you use "e.target", make sure the 'mouseChildren' property in your MC is 'false'.

If you prefer to set the child index of the clicked MC, you would do something like this:

```
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // setting the child index to 0 puts the MC at the top of the list
    container.setChildIndex(e.target, 0);
}
```

Again, any time you use "e.target" make sure 'mouseChildren' is false or else the mouse focus could actually click on display objects inside of your "clicked mc".

Comment: Also, in your case, the 'container' would be 'stage'. I would recommend putting these into another MovieClip or Sprite and add that container to the stage. This way you can add other elements to the stage and just focus on the MCs in the container.

Comment: very nice is working! 
can you explain me how to remove parenting?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove parenting"? There is no way to remove a parent. You can only remove child. The 'removeChild' method will set the 'parent' property to 'null'.

Comment: oh yeah I mean removeChild sorry
everthing is working properly. I just wanted to ask if there is a metho d like removeChild.
thank you for your help

Comment: do you know how to apply to each mc a number so that when they are in the right order on my grid something should be displayed like the original image which was used to make the mc's
thank you